# OpenMesh Random Access

Tags: mesh, vertex, indices, openmesh

I thought OpenMesh would support random access to faces edges vertices.
All I can find are iterators and circulators:

```
for( auto v : mesh->vertices() ) 
    mesh->point(v).data();
```

How can I do something like this:

```
mesh->vertices(42);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
VertexHandle    vertex_handle (unsigned int _i) const
```

this function can be use to get a vertex handler, and if you want to get the vertex from it, just use

```
mesh.point(_vh);
```

where _vh is the handle you get from the above function.